# Prove $\{x_n\}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ iff it has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Suppose the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove $\{x_n\}$ is convergent iff it has a convergent subsequence. I have two different approaches in mind. I cannot decide if they are both correct or any of them fails (hopefully not both!).

#### Method 1:

$\Longrightarrow$ Every Cauchy sequence is bbd. Every bdd sequence has a convergent subsequence.
$\Longleftarrow $ If a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges to $x$, then the sequence itself converges to $x$. (A direct proof for this part.)

Method 2:
$\Longrightarrow$ If a sequence converges, then all of its subsequences converge.
$\Longleftarrow $ If a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges to $x$, then the sequence itself converges to $x$. (A direct proof for this part.)

Comment: What is $R$?  The real numbers are complete, so every Cauchy sequence there converges.  The question only becomes interesting if $R$ is a metric space which is not known to be complete.  And then method 1 fails, because in general bounded sequences might not have convergent subsequences.

Comment: On your method 1 $\Rightarrow$,  not every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb Q$ has a subsequence which converges in $\mathbb Q$ despite being bounded

Comment: The thing is, by definition, every Cauchy sequence converges in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\implies$ is even easier. If $\{x_n\}$ is convergent then $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent subsequence of $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: In this proof, we must conser real numbers only. as the problem itself has stated. so, I do not understand why I must be worried of like rational numbers

Comment: @Robert Israel Doesn't Bolzano-Weistrass state that in $\mathbb{R}$ every  bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence? Why do you say in general is not true?. Just trying to understand

Comment: The original question had $R$, not $\mathbb R$.  It's not true in $R$ if $R$ is a metric space that is not complete.  It's trivially true in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Because no one has added an answer yet:

Convergent $\implies$ convergent subsequence is trivial. Every subsequence of a convergent sequence (including the sequence itself) converges to the same limit.

Convergent subsequence + Cauchy $\implies$ convergent is what needs to be shown. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\{x_{n}\}$ is Cauchy, I can pick $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n, m \geq N_{1} \implies |x_{n} - x_{m}| < \varepsilon/2$, and since a subsequence $x_{n_{k}} \to x^{*}$, I can pick $N_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq N_{2} \implies |x_{n_{k}} - x^{*}| < \varepsilon/2$. Now, pick $N \geq \max(N_{1}, N_{2})$ (i.e. the larger of the two, so you're big enough to satisfy both conditions). Then for any $n,k \geq N$, we have 
$$
|x_{n} - x^{*}| \leq |x_{n} - x_{n_{k}}| + |x_{n_{k}} - x^{*}| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon
$$
In essence, we've shown that given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can pick a large enough $N$ such that all terms of the subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ are close to the limit $x^{*}$, AND all terms of my sequence are close to each other. This makes sure that all terms of the sequence are close to the limit $x^{*}$.